# Adding TextView to LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android

I have 2 TextViews and I want to add those to LinearLayout, but when I ran the project, only one TextView appreared.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Thank you, Jesus!");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Dont give up on me!");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        layout.addView(textView);
        layout.addView(textView2);

        setContentView(layout);
    }

}
```

After running, textView2 was the only view present in the LinearLayout.

Can someone explain to me what was going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textView2` for calling `setText` and `setTextColor` method for `textView2` because currently you are using `textView` :

```
    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    textView2.setText("Dont give up on me!");
    textView2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Suggestion also set `height/width` for all views by calling `setLayoutParams` method

Another Suggestion : Add Orientation to Linear layout by using: `layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`